# How does the Fμω lambda calculus use C?

Tags: plutus, plutustx

While poking around in the repositories I wondered how the `sha2_256` algorithm was implemented in the `PlutusTx` module. I followed all the imports and got the following path

1. The `sha2_256` function in `PlutusTx.Builtins` is defined at [(1)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/3644b6e7fa66c01cf4669f848f59a2be1bacefd4/plutus-tx/src/PlutusTx/Builtins.hs#L115). In this module it is imported from a internal module with import name `BI`.

```
{-# INLINABLE sha2_256 #-}
-- | The SHA2-256 hash of a 'ByteString'
sha2_256 :: BuiltinByteString -> BuiltinByteString
sha2_256 = BI.sha2_256
```

2. This `BI.sha2_256` function in the `PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal` is defined at [(2)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/3644b6e7fa66c01cf4669f848f59a2be1bacefd4/plutus-tx/src/PlutusTx/Builtins/Internal.hs#L230). Here the function is wrapped in the `BuiltinByteString` type. A function is imported from the the `Hash` module.

```
{-# NOINLINE sha2_256 #-}
sha2_256 :: BuiltinByteString -> BuiltinByteString
sha2_256 (BuiltinByteString b) = BuiltinByteString $ Hash.sha2 b
```

3. This `Hash.sha2` function in the `Data.ByteString.Hash` is defined at [(3)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/3644b6e7fa66c01cf4669f848f59a2be1bacefd4/plutus-core/plutus-core/src/Data/ByteString/Hash.hs#L17). Here it gets a bit more complicated. A cryptographic hash function takes an arbitrary block of data and calculates a fixed-size bit string (the digest). Since there may be other hash function (like the SHA3_256 version in `PlutusTx`) the function is abstracted to a general hash function where the type inferred by the type application `@SHA256`). This data type and its instance of a hash algorithm is imported from `Cardano.Crypto.Hash.SHA256`.

```
-- | Hash a [[BSL.ByteString]] using the SHA-256 hash function.
sha2 :: BS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
sha2 = digest (Proxy @SHA256)
```

4. In this cardano-base package the module `Cardano.Crypto.Hash.SHA256` defines the data type `SHA256` and its instance of a hash algorithm at [(4)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-base/blob/8fe904d629194b1fbaaf2d0a4e0ccd17052e9103/cardano-crypto-class/src/Cardano/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.hs#L25). The function `sha256_libsodium` is also defined there. This function uses another function called `c_crypto_hash_sha256`, this is where it gets interesting imported from the module `Libsodium.C`.

```
data SHA256

instance HashAlgorithm SHA256 where
  type SizeHash SHA256 = 32
  hashAlgorithmName _ = "sha256"
  digest _ = sha256_libsodium
```

5. The function `c_crypto_hash_sha256` in `Cardano.Crypto.Libsodium.C` (like many other cryothographic derivatives used in cardano) is defined in [(5)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-base/blob/8fe904d629194b1fbaaf2d0a4e0ccd17052e9103/cardano-crypto-class/src/Cardano/Crypto/Libsodium/C.hs#L90). Here this function is actually import from the package Libsodium which is a library for encryption, decryption, signatures, password hashing and more written in C.

Now my question is, how is this lower level C function get used in the lower level Fμω lambda calculus onchain? Does each node just invoke/inject the C function once the lambda calculus references it?